# Use different file includes for single.php

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy

I'm beginning to convet html to Wordpress, I've some problem in `single.php` to show the post with different headers because mysite use in English and Arabic language. My site containings Arabic and English catagories and any category set or connected with menu admin page. This link show the categories in English (all categories) in the left of the site

```
http://almakinat.com/index.html
```

and this link show the categories in Arabic (كل الفئات) in the right of the site

```
http://almakinat.com/ar.html
```

The categories in English connected with category name (English) and the categories in Arabic connected with category name (Arabic) set on category admin page screen in Wordpress. I need the post content from subcategories of English category to use `header-en.php` and `footer-en.php` and the post content from subcategories of arabic category to use `header-ar.php` and `footer-ar.php`

Note:

English and Arabic category connected with categories and this categories connected with other categories only not have any post. The posts in sub of sub categories of English and Arabic categories. The structure of category for example:

```
category (English)

sub category 1

sub of sub category 1
the post1


the post2

sub category 2

sub of sub category 2
the post1


the post2

category (arabic)

sub category 11

sub of sub category 11
the post1


the post2

sub category 22

sub of sub category 22
the post1


the post2
```

So my question how to make it on single.php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make posts working with different headers and footers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198142/how-to-make-posts-working-with-different-headers-and-footers)

Comment: okay I deleted the duplicate question,

I need the answer for this question please